# Finding the time interval between two events using CCP on PIC18f4520

Tags: microcontrollers, pic

I'm trying to calculate the time elapsed between two events using the `CCP` on **PIC18F4520**. The events are triggered by two sensors that are on the `ccp1` and `ccp2` ports. I've assigned a prescalar of 8 to the `T1CON` and I'm using a crystal of 16 MHz. (Duration of one clock cycle is 2e-6 s)
Since the maximum time I can measure before overflowing is just 0.13 seconds (65536 x 2e-6) and the event I'm measuring lasts for around 0.32 seconds I decided to count the number of times `TMR1IF` overflows and then multiply this by 65536 and add this to the captured `CCPR1H:CCPR1L` value.

However, I'm unable to count beyond one overflow of the `TMR1IF` register.

Hope someone knows why!

Below are the associated functions

```
void ccp_Init(void)
{
    TRISCbits.RC2 = 1;
    TRISCbits.RC1 = 1;
    CCP1CON = 0x05;
    CCP2CON = 0x05;
    T3CON = 0x00;
    PIE1bits.CCP1IE=1;
    PIE2bits.CCP2IE=1;
    T1CON = 0x30;
    TMR1H = 0;
    TMR1L = 0;
    PIR1bits.CCP1IF = 0;
    PIR2bits.CCP2IF = 0;
    PIR1bits.TMR1IF = 0;
}

int ccp_get(void)
{
    int count = 0;
    TMR1L = 0;
    TMR1H = 0;
    while(PIR2bits.CCP2IF == 0);
    T1CONbits.TMR1ON = 1;
    while (PIR1bits.CCP1IF == 0);
    {
        if (PIR1bits.TMR1IF == 1)
        {
            PIR1bits.TMR1IF = 0;
            TMR1L = 0;
            TMR1H = 0;
            count = count+1;
            T1CONbits.TMR1ON = 1;
        }
    }
    T1CONbits.TMR1ON = 0;
    return count;
}
```

From the above code `int ccp_get()` returns the number of times TMR1IF has overflowed and which isn't going beyond 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This loop looks suspicious, try removing the semicolon on first line:

```
while (PIR1bits.CCP1IF == 0);
{
    if (PIR1bits.TMR1IF == 1)
    {
        PIR1bits.TMR1IF = 0;
        TMR1L = 0;
        TMR1H = 0;
        count = count+1;
        T1CONbits.TMR1ON = 1;
    }
}
```

Overall, I suggest not to clear the timer counter. You could possibly miss some interrupts. Overflow happens after roll over, so the value would be already reset. See [Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39631a.pdf) on page 130 it says:

> The TMR1 register pair (TMR1H:TMR1L) increments from 0000h to FFFFh
>   and rolls over to 0000h. The Timer1 interrupt, if enabled, is
>   generated on overflow, which is latched in interrupt flag bit, TMR1IF
>   (PIR1<0>). This interrupt can be enabled or disabled by setting or
>   clearing the Timer1 Interrupt Enable bit, TMR1IE (PIE1<0>).